# ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in AccountsController#profile

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

Unexpected end when end exists, But I don't see where the issue is.
My terminal keeps giving me the error: ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate (Encountered a syntax error while rendering template:

my profile.html.erb

```
<% if @users.image.present?  %>
  <%= image_tag @users.image %>
<% end %>

<strong><h1><%= @users.full_name %></h1></strong>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if @user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to"Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %>
    <% if user_signed_in? && !@user? %>
      <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
       <%= link_to"Unfollow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :delete %>
      <% else %>
       <%= link_to"Follow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id) %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<div> <%= @users.posts.count %> Posts </div>
<p><%= @users.full_name %></p>
<p><%= @users.description %></p>
<p><%= link_to @users.website if @users.website.present? %></p>
<%= @posts.each do |post|%>
<%= image_tag post.image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Start by looking at the error message and finding the offending line. I'm guessing that its connected to `<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>`.

Comment: It is difficult to find such errors when the code is not indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if user_signed_in? && @user == current_user %>

      <%= link_to"Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %>
    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
        <%= link_to"Unfollow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to"Follow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

now it's ok :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue is here

```
<p><%= link_to @users.website if @users.website.present? %></p>
```

Change it to

```
<p><%= link_to 'User Website', @users.website if @users.website.present? %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen two mistakes, please correct them. first there is nothing `@user?` that is biggest error, another might not be problem but there is no space `<%= link_to"Edit Profile"` Please try following code I have changed things and reformat it properly.

```
<% if @users.image.present? %>
  <%= image_tag @users.image %>
<% end %>

<strong><h1><%= @users.full_name %></h1></strong>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if @user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %>
    <% if user_signed_in? && !@user %>
      <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
        <%= link_to"Unfollow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :delete %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to"Follow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<div> <%= @users.posts.count %> Posts </div>
<p><%= @users.full_name %></p>
<p><%= @users.description %></p>
<p><%= link_to @users.website if @users.website.present? %></p>
<%= @posts.each do |post|%>
  <%= image_tag post.image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you mr.Kamal but i still have another error in my user.rb model (around line #28): ``` 26
27def following?(user)
28following.include?(user)
29end 
30```

Comment: Well that is different question, so make it separate with explaining error and community will guide you.

Comment: You are correct that `!@user?` is the issue. This is read by the parser as an attempted ternary e.g. `!@user ? true : false` however the additional `true : false` portion is missing so when the parser finds the `end` it does not know what to do with it. The other part about the `link_to` just looks bad however it is technically syntactically allowable e.g. `def hello(name);name;end` then `hello"engineersmnky" #=> "engineersmnky"` because the parser does recognize the `String` as the argument to the `hello` method. That being said this is very limited to `String` arguments so best to avoid it.